# Why are double glazed windows useful in summer?

Tags: windows

Why are double glazed windows useful in summer

Answer (score 2):

Double glazed windows help in controlling the inside temperature keeping it warmer in winter and cooler in summer, making it a smart way to reduce heating and cooling costs. Double glazing is quite effective as it stops all heat transfer from one side to another. It also stops UV damage.

Comment: +1 for UV damage. Argon gas is used in double pane glass for thermal qualities too. Here’s an excellent article https://www.stanekwindows.com/what-are-the-benefits-of-argon-gas-in-windows.aspx

Comment: The dead airspace or filled chamber reduces the heat transfer can't stop it completely but other than that +.

Comment: "Stops all"? No. Even a complete vacuum allows some radiant transfer of both heat energy and UV light.

Comment: Double-glazed windows can also have a "low-e" coating on the inside that reduces infrared and ultraviolet light transmission to reduce heat transfer while maintaining visible light transmission.

Answer (score 0):

They are great for hot and cold environments. Depending on whether you are keeping hot or cold out the insulated glass units are built differently. That's the basics it actually can be quite complicated once you throw all the options on the table.